# getting an issue when adding strings?

Tags: python, string

I am having issues with the second to last 'elif' statement, I am getting the concatenation error with str and integers-> any explanation to why this is? My understanding is that I am adding a string "R" to the empty string next_row.

Specifically the error is "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

```
  def triangle(row):
     next_row = ''

     for i in row:
         if i == 'G' and (i + 1) == 'B':
             next_row += 'R'

         elif i == 'G' and (i + 1) == 'R':
             next_row += 'B'

         elif i == 'R' and (i + 1) == 'B':
             next_row += 'G'

         elif i == 'R' and (i + 1) == 'G':
             next_row += 'B'

         elif i == 'B' and (i + 1) == 'G':
             next_row += 'R'

         elif i == 'B' and (i + 1) == 'R':
             next_row += 'G'

     print(type(next_row))
     return None

 triangle("BRGGBRG")
```

Comment: `i+1` tries to add a string to an integer, that doesn't make sense. You might want to `enumerate()` your `row`.

Comment: Why did you think this `(i + 1) == 'B'` would work? You are trying to add a string with an integer. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If `i` is `'G'`, a string, `i+1` is `'G' + 1`, which is not a legal operation in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `(i + 1)`. Python does not know what to do with that.
Python cannot resolve `'A' + 1`.

I presume that when you say `(i + 1)` you are trying to look at the next iteration of `row`.

Instead, iterate over `range(0, len(row))`. Use `row[i]` to see the current value, and `row[i + 1]` to look at the next one.

```py
def triangle(row):
    next_row = ''

    for i in range(0, len(row)):
        if row[i] == 'G' and row[i + 1] == 'B':
            next_row += 'R'

        elif row[i] == 'G' and row[i + 1] == 'R':
            next_row += 'B'

        elif row[i] == 'R' and row[i + 1] == 'B':
            next_row += 'G'

        elif row[i] == 'R' and row[i + 1] == 'G':
            next_row += 'B'

        elif row[i] == 'B' and row[i + 1] == 'G':
            next_row += 'R'

        elif row[i] == 'B' and row[i + 1] == 'R':
            next_row += 'G'

    print(type(next_row))
    return None

triangle("BRGGBRG ")
```

Note that using `row[i + 1]` on the last value will result in a run time error, since there won't be a next value.

Answer (score 0):

String in python is iterable objects.
So, when you use for loop on string object, the variable `i` will be every character in string.

You might want to use enumerate with iterable object to get the index.

```py
def triangle(row):
    next_row = ''

    # index means the index of for loop
    for index, i in enumerate(row):
        if index+1 == len(row):
            # Do Whatever you wnat to do with the lastest character
            break

        if i == 'G' and row[index + 1] == 'B':
            next_row += 'R'

        elif i == 'G' and row[index + 1] == 'R':
             next_row += 'B'

         elif i == 'R' and row[index + 1] == 'B':
             next_row += 'G'

         elif i == 'R' and row[index + 1] == 'G':
             next_row += 'B'

         elif i == 'B' and row[index + 1] == 'G':
             next_row += 'R'

         elif i == 'B' and row[index + 1] == 'R':
             next_row += 'G'
    return None
```